# Como determinar el nombre del primer empleado que ya cumplio un año utilizando GregorianCalendar en un array

Tags: java, array

me estoy metiendo en el terreno de las fechas y sus metodos, como hago para determinar con gregoriancalendar cual de todos los empleados ya cumplio un año? Teniendo en cuenta la fecha actual, tengo los objetos en un array. Hay muchos metodos pero no se cual podria servirme.

```
package recursos;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Personal {

private String nombre;
private String sexo;
private Date fechaNacimiento;

public Personal(String nombre, String sexo, int agno, int mes, int dia) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    GregorianCalendar cal=new GregorianCalendar(agno, mes-1, dia);
    fechaNacimiento=cal.getTime();

}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
    return fechaNacimiento;
}

public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
    this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
}


}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here
    BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Date fechaActual=new Date(2018, 11, 23);


    Personal[] empleados = new Personal[6];
    empleados[0] = new Administrativo("Maria", "Femenino", 1978, 11, 01);
    empleados[1] = new Gerente("Jose", "Trans", 1988, 01, 22);
    empleados[2] = new Obrero("Natalia", "Femenino", 1990, 12, 30);
    empleados[3] = new Obrero("Albero", "Masculino", 1986, 04, 12);
    empleados[4] = new Obrero("Carlos", "Femenino", 1990, 12, 11);
    empleados[5] = new Visitante("Irma", "Femenino", 1972, 12, 03);  


    for (Personal empleado : empleados) {
        System.out.println(empleado.getFechaNacimiento());
    }

    } 

}
```

Gracias por la eventual ayuda!

Comment: http://mickinfo.blogspot.com/2011/08/restar-dos-fechas-gregorian-calendar.html

Answer (score 0):

Usa mejor clases del paquete java.time, como por ejemplo `LocalDate`

```
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class Personal {

    private String nombre;
    private String sexo;
    private LocalDate fechaNacimiento;

    public Personal(String nombre, String sexo, int agno, int mes, int dia) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.fechaNacimiento = LocalDate.of(agno, mes, dia);//mes va de 1 a 12

    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(LocalDate fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }


}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // TODO code application logic here
        BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));



        Personal[] empleados = new Personal[6];
        empleados[0] = new Administrativo("Maria", "Femenino", 1978, 11, 01);
        empleados[1] = new Gerente("Jose", "Trans", 1988, 01, 22);
        empleados[2] = new Obrero("Natalia", "Femenino", 1990, 12, 30);
        empleados[3] = new Obrero("Albero", "Masculino", 1986, 04, 12);
        empleados[4] = new Obrero("Carlos", "Femenino", 1990, 12, 11);
        empleados[5] = new Visitante("Irma", "Femenino", 1972, 12, 03);  

        Stream.of(empleados).filter(Personal::tieneMasDeUnAnio).forEach(System.out::println);

    } 
    public static boolean tieneMasDeUnAnio(Personal empleado){
            return ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(empleado.getFechaNacimiento(), LocalDate.now())>=1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, me tira este error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at recursos.Personal.tieneMasDeUnAnio(Personal.java:53)
 at principal.Principal.main(Principal.java:34)
C:\Users\luna\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: ¿Qué versión de java usas?

Comment: Utilizó la versión 8

Comment: Prueba con el código modificado